# 'Failed to halt - Process 1932 has exited with status 0'

Tags: go, cmd, visual-studio-code

I've only recently started experiencing an issue in Visual Studio Code while running applications in debug mode, I always get this error:

> Failed to halt - Process 2152 has exited with status 0

Just after `main()` function exits, even when I import only `fmt` package and print "Hello World", or running applications those were previously working.

I pulled same project on another machine and run it (for example "Hello World" project). I'm getting the same error message.

Has anyone else experienced the same? It doesn't seem to occur when I run built applications using `cmd` (command prompt).

Comment: "when running built applications from the Cmd console" using delve? Or just running them normally? I would expect results to be different when debugging versus when just running an application. Have you tried updating delve?

Comment: I have reinstalled the Go extension for VS Code, afaik this has the latest version of delve. Is there a go get style command I can use to pull and update the version, or check the version I have? many thanks.

Comment: VSCode's Go extension comes with a "Go: Install/Update Tools" command. Try running it by pressing ctrl+shift+P and typing it into the command palette. Delve is in the list of tools it'll download.

Comment: I've run this command successfully and been told it's fully up-to-date, however I'm still having the same issue

Comment: AFAIK, when you debug the order of the code that is being executed does not necessarily correspond to the order of your instructions.
Take a look at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/blob/master/src/debugAdapter/goDebug.ts
The debugger may not be able to send a halt command due to compilation. It once happened on a project I worked on and after rewriting some of the work-in-progress code it suddenly started halting properly.